# Python Tkinter Text-Widget scroll to specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x, scroll, tkinter, text-widget

Issue:

- Loading a code-file from the harddrive into a text-widget created by tkinter (may be larger than xxx lines)
- Finding a position within this text-widget (line/column)
- Scrolling the text-widget to that exact position

So far I could not find any way to scroll to a specific line in a Tkinter text-widget.
Since Tkinter always uses the line/column (e.g. "1.0") notation to identify positions in the text-widget, isn't there a way to directly scroll to a given position?

So far I tried setting the yview directly:

```
textWidget.yview("scroll", scrollamount, "units")
```

But that seems very unclean to me to use the "units" here...

Looking for a clean solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> help(Tkinter.Text.see)
Help on method see in module Tkinter:

see(self, index) unbound Tkinter.Text method
    Scroll such that the character at INDEX is visible.
```

To make sure line 3 is visible do:

```
textWidget.see('3.0')
```